# how to find the query executed when dynamic workbook exported from Dynamics CRM?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016, vba

how to find the query executed when dynamic workbook exported from Dynamics CRM?

Basically we have Microsoft `Dynamics CRM` tool to track the requests received within our team.I have created a customized view with my requirement and had exported the data into a `Dynamic Workbook` so that each time the `xml` file is opened the data gets refreshed automatically.

I wanted to do the below:

1. Know which query is ran behind the scenes to update the data in the
   workbook?
2. I wanted to export the xml into another worksheet of
   another dynamic workbbook so that i have consolidated data

Could someone please help me in this ?

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you an answer for your second question, but for your first, create a retrieve multiple plugin that executes on all entities, and log the query expression that is found in the Plugin Context.

Shouldn't take too long to narrow it down...